# PHP Easy Coding Standard (ECS) - suppress phpcs warnings

Tags: php, suppress-warnings, phpcs

ECS = symplify/easy-coding-standard
I am getting an message when running ECS:

```
Unused variable $validator.
(SlevomatCodingStandard\Sniffs\Variables\UnusedVariableSniff.UnusedVariable)
```

For this code:

```
// phpcs:ignore
// @codingStandardsIgnoreLine
foreach ($this->rules as $attribute => $validator) {
```

I did try using the suppress comments in different setup:

- only one of them
- on the same line as the message suggests
- in different order
- by targeting specific warning:

  - SlevomatCodingStandard\Sniffs\Variables\UnusedVariableSniff.UnusedVariable
  - SlevomatCodingStandard.Variables.UnusedVariable

Does any one know if ECS supports inline suppress comments?
In the ECS documentation I see it's only possible to suppress whole file.

PS. I know I can use array_keys(), but the goal in this case is to suppress the warnings, as in the future it can be a different one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or... as variant add rule to config file easy-coding-standard.yaml

```
services:
  SlevomatCodingStandard\Sniffs\Variables\UnusedVariableSniff:
    ignoreUnusedValuesWhenOnlyKeysAreUsedInForeach: true
```